# When doing feature selection based on mutual information, should it be normalized?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, signal-processing, mutual-information

Are any kind of normalizations useful when using mutual information to select features?

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information#Normalized_variants) has a few variants but they don't seem helpful. The entropy of the response is a constant and the entropy of the features ($H(X)$) doesn't seem relevant since they are fixed when I'm making predictions.

Comment: It seems this question has been answered here, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1357/is-mutual-information-invariant-to-scaling-i-e-multiplying-all-elements-by-a-n

Comment: Normalizing is not just scaling since $H(X)$ depends on which feature is being evaluated.